# How to install torch 0.4.1 on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, pytorch

I have windows 10 on a Lenovo Thinkpad P72 with a Nvidia Quadro P5200, and I absolutely need to install (py)torch v0.4.1 to use a *3D* Mask R-CNN. So I tried the following link:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19457

However, when I finish with "python setup.py install", I obtain:

```
C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build>msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine, version 4.8.3752.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

La génération a démarré 31/03/2020 07:03:00.
Projet "C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build\INSTALL.vcxproj" sur le noud 1 (cibles par défaut).
C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build\INSTALL.vcxproj(32,3): error MSB4019: Le projet importé     "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" est introuvable. Vérifiez que le chemin d'accès dans la     déclaration <Import> est correct et que le fichier existe sur le disque.
Génération du projet "C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build\INSTALL.vcxproj" terminée (cibles par défaut) -- ÉCHEC.


ÉCHEC de la build.

"C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build\INSTALL.vcxproj" (cible par défaut) (1) -> C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build\INSTALL.vcxproj(32,3): error MSB4019: Le projet importé     "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" est introuvable. Vérifiez que le chemin d'accès dans la déclaration <Import> est correct et que le fichier existe sur le disque.

0 Avertissement(s)
1 Erreur(s)

Temps écoulé 00:00:00.28

C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build>IF ERRORLEVEL 1 exit 1
Failed to run 'tools\build_pytorch_libs.bat --use-cuda --use-nnpack caffe2 nanopb libshm_windows'
```

Since I wasn't able to solve this issue, I copied all the missing files there, and then I obtained (even if C:\Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll exists):

```
ÉCHEC de la build.

"C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build\INSTALL.vcxproj" (cible par défaut) (1) ->
"C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (cible par défaut) (2) ->
(SetBuildDefaultEnvironmentVariables cible) -> C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets(64,5): error MSB4062: Impossible de charger la tâche "SetEnv" à partir de l'assembly
C:\Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll. Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly         'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...' ou une     de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. Assurez-vous que la déclaration     <UsingTask> est correcte, que l'assembly et toutes ses dépendances sont
disponibles et que la tâche contient une classe publique qui implémente     Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\Users\...\pytorch-0.4.1\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]
```

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 7):

Installation via pip:

```
pip install torch==0.4.1 torchvision==0.2.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: torchvision 0.5.0 is not compatible with PyTorch 0.4.1 better to replace it with different version

Answer (score 0):

Try using anaconda to install torch.

Use [this link](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) to download `pytorch`.